# How to reference third-party libraries, eg breeze, from eclipse, when working with Scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I have Eclipse, with eclipse-ide plugin installed, and with 'sbt' selected as the builder.  I want to use a third-party library, specifically scala-breeze, and I'm not sure how to instruct eclipse/scala-ide to fetch and install this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `breeze` dependency via `sbt`, then run the `sbt eclipse` command to get everything configured. The command must be run each time something in the build changes.